# How to compare html input value in django?

Tags: python, django, input

I am allowing users to input certain data. I got the user input data in the Django view.py but when I try to compare the user with other data. It doesn't work properly

```
def compare(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get('data')
        if data == 'yes':
           print("no")
        elif data == 'menu':
           print(True)
```

html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="your_name"> Specific Data </label>
    <input type="text" name="data" placeholder="Enter yes or menu "> <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

I entered the "menu" on the input section but it is working with a ( " if data == 'yes' ) statement

Comment: the problem is your are not sending the data to the server.to do that you can use ajax or create forms.py are you familiar with ajax or jquery ?

Comment: @amadousow no, I don't. I only know Django and HTML. It is sending to the server but it's working properly

Comment: do this print(request.POST) do you get any data ?

Comment: @amadousow yes, I got the data

Comment: could you show what you got ?

Comment: @amadousow it was working but my computer was crashed. I restart my computer and run the program again and it was working fine.